# In weaviate is it possible to return only some referenced objects in Weaviate?

Tags: weaviate

It is for an e-commerce use case.

We sell products and products have different properties depending on the city, e.g. price, availability etc..
When we query for a product, we always want to filter with a city and only want to return information for that city.

Within Weaviate I built 2 classes City and Product.

```
class Product:
   brand: string
   picture: string
   cities: List[city]

class City:
   cityId: String
   additionalInfo: String
```

I can't seem to find a way to query Weaviate so that it returns only the reference/data to the single matching city. Instead, it returns the product and information for all cities.
Below is the query I am using.

```
{
  Get {
        Product(
          where: {
            operator: And
            operands: [
              {
                path: ["cities", "City", "cityId"]
                operator: Equal
                valueString: "12121"
              }
              { path: ["brand"], operator: Equal, valueString: "Goro" }
            ]
          }
          nearVector: { vector: [1, 1, 1, 1] }
        ) {
          sku
          responseBody
          cities {
            ... on City {
              CityId
              additionalInfo
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Can someone suggest a way that I could improve on the query to return only a single city? If this is not possible, could someone suggest a better schema to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Hi @Funzo – just to make sure I understand correctly, you mean that the query above also gives _other_ `City`'s beside those where `cityId == 12121 `?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will explain how the query you wrote is actually interpreted.

Let's call this part of the query `A`:

```
{
                path: ["cities", "City", "cityId"]
                operator: Equal
                valueString: "12121"
              }
```

`A` will return all Products where the cityId is 12121

Let's call this part of the query `B`:

```
 { path: ["brand"], operator: Equal, valueString: "Goro" }
```

`B` will return all Products where the brand is Goro.

`A` `And` `B` will return the products that are common to both `A` and `B` so the final result is just Goro branded products.

There's already an issue to support a new query syntax that will produce the result you want. Here's the issue: https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/2477

Would be great if you can upvote it so that weaviate team can prioritise it accordingly.